# Change layout of student registration in tutor lms

Tags: layout, user-registration

I am using tutor LMS plug-in.
The form of student registration appears 1 field only per row and the label of the field found at the top of each field so, I need to scroll down to complete the form and click submit

I need to display 2 fields per row and prevent label to appear to be able to complete form without scroll down

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: User registration in tutor lms layout display one field per row . I need to display 2 field per row so the user do not need to scroll down the screen to fill them